# Slow MySQL SELECT on large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for storing prices over time of ~35k items every 15 minutes for 2 weeks.. Roughly it translates to about 35 million rows in the table. I'm trying to perform the simplest of queries:

```
SELECT buy_price, sell_price, created_at FROM price_archive WHERE item_id = X
```

The first, uncached run of that query takes around 4-7 seconds to return ~1300 rows (per item). This seems ridiculously slow for something so trivial for a database, especially considering there is on index on the `item_id` column.

The table has 35k rows inserted every 15 minutes, and each day a task runs to delete items from < (2 weeks - 1) ago (to stop the table from growing too much). I suspect this fragments the table quite a bit, but would that fragmentation cause the query to perform so poorly? If yes, would partitioning on `created_at` for the deletion of old data make it better?

```
1306 rows in set (8.32 sec)

mysql> explain select * from price_archives where item_id = 743;
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys                   | key                             | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | price_archives | ref  | index_price_archives_on_item_id | index_price_archives_on_item_id | 5       | const | 1305 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: I would recommend you to run the OPTIMIZE command and then run the SELECT query above to see if it runs faster. If it is, then you know the defragmentation is causing it to be slow. Also the index you are currently using may not be the most optimized one for this specific query. Try creating an index with item_id,buyprice,sellprice,created_at.

Comment: Instead of running an optimize and locking the table to new inserts, I'm going to clone the table and then try the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT buy_price, sell_price, created_at
FROM price_archive
WHERE item_id = X;
```

The best index for this query is the composite index:  `price_archive(item_id, buy_price, sell_price, created_at)`.  This is a "covering" index that can satisfy the query.  It comes with a downside, though.  This index may slow the inserts that you are doing in the table.  140k rows every hour is a lot of data, but this maintaining this index should not be so bad.

You are facing a not-uncommon challenge in databases.  The problem with your query is that the 1300 or so rows being returned are all on different data pages.  In all likelihood, the table does not fit into memory on your machine, so this results in about 1300 accesses to the files on disk.  That explains why you are seeing a lag time of several seconds.

Another solution is to ensure that the data tables themselves fit into memory.  Although the first uncached query will take a bit of time, subsequent queries should be quite fast.

Comment: If those fields were the full contents of the table itself, would a covering index use up as much RAM as the table occupies on the disk (i.e. 2GB)?

Comment: @Supremacy . . . It would actually occupy a bit more space.  But the data would be structured exactly the way the query needs it.  The advantage is that all the data for a given `item_id` would be colocated in the index, so there is no need to go to many different data pages to gather the information.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I can't really afford such a large index so I've decided to aggregate the older data to a lower resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add indexes to the table columns.

Had this problem to with a million+ records, and the time went from 50 seconds to 10 seconds.

The SQL Query to update the table:

```
ALTER TABLE price_archives ADD INDEX (item_id);
ALTER TABLE price_archives ADD INDEX (buy_price);
ALTER TABLE price_archives ADD INDEX (sell_price);
ALTER TABLE price_archives ADD INDEX (created_at);
```